# My React (not strict mode) function executes twice in swipe gesture

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, nextui

I have some kind of a swipe functionality on list items in my React application. The swipe functionality is working, but somehow the right swipe function gets executed twice. I am not using React StrictMode, so that isn't the problem.

Here is my list item component simplified:

```
<Card 
        isPressable={!finished} 
        onClick={() => {
            handleClick(false);
        }}
        onTouchStart={(e) => {
            setTouchEnd(null);
            setTouchStart(e.targetTouches[0].clientX);
        }}
        onTouchMove={(e) => {
            setTouchEnd(e.targetTouches[0].clientX);
        }}
        onTouchEnd={() => {
            if (!touchStart || !touchEnd) return;
            const distance = touchStart - touchEnd;
            const isLeftSwipe = distance > minSwipeDistance;
            const isRightSwipe = distance < -minSwipeDistance;
            if(isLeftSwipe && finished) {
                handleLeftSwipe();
            }
            else if(isRightSwipe && !finished) { 
                handleRightSwipe(); 
            }
        }} 
        onContextMenu={() => handleClick(true)}
```

minSwipeDistance is a const: const minSwipeDistance = 50;

The onTouchEnd also executes twice when I swipe right. The handleSwipeRight function itself doesn't need to be debugged, because I literally exchanged it for only a console log and it was still being executed twice.

For the rest I am not doing anything special in my `useEffects`.

A listitem should not be able to be swiped left when the item is not finished and vice versa for finished items with right swipe.

[image]
[image]
[image]

My whole list Item component:
(swipedRight state is only for CSS purposes)

```
import { Avatar, Card, Modal, Row, Text } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { finishOrderRule, showToast, getOrderRule } from "../../utils/api.js";
import { useAuth } from "../../App.js";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faInfo } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

export default function OrderRule(props){

    const [amountOfFields, setAmountOfFields] = useState(props.datafields?.length);
    const [finished, setFinished] = useState(props.data?.Finished);
    const [swipedLeft, setSwipedLeft] = useState(false);
    const [swipedRight, setSwipedRight] = useState(false);
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [touchStart, setTouchStart] = useState(null);
    const [touchEnd, setTouchEnd] = useState(null);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(props.selected === props.data?.Oid);

    const order = props.order;
    const isAllRules = props.isAllRules;
    const rule = props.data;
    const datafields = props.datafields;
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { token } = useAuth();
    const minSwipeDistance = 50; 

    const noteField = {
        name: "Note", 
        type: "Regels", 
        label: "Notitie"
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setSelected(props.selected === rule?.Oid);
    }, [props.selected]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setAmountOfFields(props.datafields.length);
    }, [props.datafields]);

    function getParts(fieldname, isOrderProperty){
        const parts = fieldname.split(".");
        if(parts.length === 1) return isOrderProperty ? order?.[fieldname] : rule?.[fieldname];
        else if (parts.length === 2) return isOrderProperty ? order?.[parts[0]]?.[parts[1]] : rule?.[parts[0]]?.[parts[1]];
    }

    function handleClick(long){
        if (long) navigate(`/orders/${order?.Oid}/${rule?.Oid}`, { state: rule, replace: false });
        else props.setSelectedRule(rule?.Oid);
    }

    function handleIconClick(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        setIsOpen(true);
    }

    function handleRightSwipe(){
        console.log("right swipe");
        setSwipedRight(true);
        setFinished(true);
        finishOrderRule(rule?.Oid, true, token)
            .catch(error => {
                setFinished(false);
                if(error.statusCode === 401) {
                    showToast("Je moet opnieuw inloggen of je hebt geen rechten om deze actie uit te voeren.", error.statusCode);
                    navigate("/login");
                }
                else { 
                    showToast(error.message, error.statusCode)
                    console.log(error); 
                }
            })
            .finally(() => {
                getOrderRule(rule?.Oid, token)
                    .then((data) => {
                        props.modifyRule(data.value[0]);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        setFinished(true);
                        if(error.statusCode === 401) {
                            showToast("Je moet opnieuw inloggen of je hebt geen rechten om deze actie uit te voeren.", error.statusCode);
                            navigate("/login");
                        }
                        else { 
                            showToast(error.message, error.statusCode)
                            console.log(error); 
                        }
                    })
                    .finally(() => {
                        setSwipedRight(false);
                        props.setSelectedRule(null);
                    });
            });
    }

    function handleLeftSwipe(){
        console.log("left swipe");
        setSwipedLeft(true);
        setFinished(false);
        finishOrderRule(rule?.Oid, false, token)
            .catch(error => {
                setFinished(true);
                if(error.statusCode === 401) {
                    showToast("Je moet opnieuw inloggen of je hebt geen rechten om deze actie uit te voeren.", error.statusCode);
                    navigate("/login");
                }
                else { 
                    showToast(error.message, error.statusCode)
                    console.log(error); 
                }
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setSwipedLeft(false);
                getOrderRule(rule?.Oid, token)
                    .then((data) => {
                        props.modifyRule(data.value[0]);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        setFinished(true);
                        if(error.statusCode === 401) {
                            showToast("Je moet opnieuw inloggen of je hebt geen rechten om deze actie uit te voeren.", error.statusCode);
                            navigate("/login");
                        }
                        else { 
                            showToast(error.message, error.statusCode)
                            console.log(error); 
                        }
                    })
                    .finally(() => {});
            });
    }

    function isDate(fieldname){ return fieldname.toLowerCase().includes("date") }
    
    const ModalComponent = () => {
        return (
            <Modal css={{zIndex: 10, m: 10}} closeButton open={isOpen} onClose={() => { setIsOpen(false); }}>
                <Modal.Header css={{p: 0}}><Text color="primary" size={26}>{rule?.Product?.Name}</Text></Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body css={{p: 20, pt: 0}}>
                    <Text weight="medium" size={15} css={{textAlign: "center"}}>{rule?.Product?.Description}</Text>     
                    <Text weight="medium" size={15} css={{textAlign: "center"}}>{rule?.Note}</Text>     
                </Modal.Body>   
            </Modal>
        );
    }

    const NoteField = ({ width }) => {
        return (
            <div style={{pointerEvents: "none", width: width, display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignContent: "center"}}>
                {(rule?.Note !== null && 
                    <Avatar onClick={(e) => handleIconClick(e)} color={"white"} size="sm" css={{display: "flex", pointerEvents: "auto", border: "2px solid black", alignContent: "center", justifyContent: "center", justifyItems: "center", alignItems: "center"}} bordered icon={<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfo} />} />) || (
                    <Avatar color={"white"} size="sm" css={{border: "2px solid black", opacity: "10%"}} bordered icon={<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfo} />} />)}
            </div>
        );
    }

    const Field = ({ field }) => {
        const obj = field.type === "Orders" ? getParts(field.name, true) : getParts(field.name, false);
        const wi = ((100 / amountOfFields).toString() + "%").toString();
        return field.name === "Note" ? <NoteField width={wi} /> : <Text weight="medium" size={15} css={{pointerEvents: "none", width: wi, textAlign: "center", lineHeight: "100%"}}>{isDate(field.name) ? new Date(obj).toLocaleDateString().toString() : typeof(obj) === "boolean" ? (obj === true ? "Ja" : "Nee") : obj === "" ? "-" : obj === null ? "-" : obj}</Text>;
    }
    
    return (
        <Card 
            isPressable={!finished} 
            onClick={() => { handleClick(false); }}
            onTouchStart={(e) => {
                setTouchEnd(null);
                setTouchStart(e.targetTouches[0].clientX);
            }}
            onTouchMove={(e) => {
                setTouchEnd(e.targetTouches[0].clientX);
            }}
            onTouchEnd={() => {
                if (!touchStart || !touchEnd) return;
                const distance = touchStart - touchEnd;
                const isLeftSwipe = distance > minSwipeDistance;
                const isRightSwipe = distance < -minSwipeDistance;
                if(isLeftSwipe && finished) {
                    handleLeftSwipe();
                }
                if(isRightSwipe && !finished) { 
                    handleRightSwipe();
                }
            }} 
            onContextMenu={() => handleClick(true)}
            css={{p: "0px 10px 0px 10px", w: 'auto', m: "6.5px", h: "55px", justifyContent: "center"}}
            className={
                finished && swipedRight ? "listItem swipedRight finished" : 
                finished && swipedLeft ? "listItem swipedLeft finished" : 
                selected && swipedRight ? "listItem selected swipedRight" : 
                selected ? "listItem selected" : 
                swipedLeft ? "listItem swipedLeft" : 
                swipedRight ? "listItem swipedRight" : 
                finished ? "listItem finished" : 
                "listItem"
            }
        >
            <ModalComponent key="modal" />
            {isAllRules && <div style={selected ? {position: 'absolute', left: 2, top: -4.5} : {position: 'absolute', left: 5, top: -2.5}}><Text size={13} color="primary">{`Order ${order?.Number}`}</Text></div>}
            <Row justify="space-evenly" css={{alignItems: "center"}}>
                {datafields.map((field) => (
                    <Field key={field.name} field={field} />
                ))}
                <Field key="Notitie" field={noteField} />
            </Row>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched UI-libraries from Next.UI to Mantine.dev and somehow that fixed this issue.

I think it had something to do with the rendering of the Card component.